# Grunt livecompiling less using watch

Tags: gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-watch

I know there are some quite similar questions, but I can't get it to work.

I'm using grunt, including **connect, less and watch**. Everything works, except for the livecompiling of the .css with less and watch. Like this, I always have to restart grunt etc.
This is my code:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    port: 8000,
                    hostname: 'localhost',
                    base: 'public',
                    keepalive: true
                }
            }
        },
        less: {
            development: {
                options: {
                    compress: true,
                    yuicompress: true,
                    optimization: 2
                },
                files: {
                    "public/style/style.css": "public/style/main.less"
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            files: ['**/*'],
            tasks: ['less', 'connect'],

            styles: {
                files: ['public/style/main.less'], //which files to watch
                tasks: ['less'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['less','connect','watch']);
};
```

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the livereload snippet in your html file to get it works:

```
<script>
   document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"><\/script>')
</script>
```

`35729` is the port of your livereload server.

To further information see the [documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionslivereload). Also you should read [how to enable livereload in your html](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/master/docs/watch-examples.md#enabling-live-reload-in-your-html).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mario's answer, I tried around a little.

I found the solution like this:
I ran **watch** alone, without less or connect and I noticed that it left something in the console, which I did **not** see in the console when I had it running in combination with connect and less. Next thing I noticed was the "Waiting forever..." in **connect**'s entry in the console. Like this, nothing happenend, because it waited forever. The consequence of this was that **watch** could not be executed. That also explains why I never **watch**'s entry in the console.

So the solution was this:
I had to delete "keepalive:true" from **connect** in the Gruntfile.